# Find Algorithm over Map Keyset (c++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, keyset

Is there a way to use the .find(itr, itr, value) algorithm over the keyset of a map? I know you could use an iterator over the map to transfer the key values into a set (and then use that), but I wasn't sure if there was a quicker way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be best off using `std::map<K, V>`'s `find()` member because this takes advantage of the `map`s internal structure. If you really want to find sonething, e.g., because you are looking just for an attribute in the key, you'd need to use `std::find_if()`:

```
auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(),
    [=](decltype(*m.begin()) const& e){
        return e.first == v;
    });
```